# Запрос не влияет на адресную строку

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-router

Использую API `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api` сделал пагинацию с помощью `fetch`, но если я хочу в ручную перейти на страницу `/character?page=10`, то всегда отображается то, что находится на первой странице. Сама пагинация работает. Страницы переключаются, но запрос видимо не меняется...

**Вопрос:**
Как сделать так, чтобы при смене страницы в адресной строке `/character?page=10` он запоминал это и выдавал именно то, что находится на этой странице? [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Fillsen/849102f74b3ac9b0b732bd31a4bac82c)

Сам метод фетча страниц:

```js
    // Fetching Page
    const fetchPage = (page) => {
        // Init loading while page load
        setLoading(true);
        const query = `${url}?page=${page}`;
        fetchData(query);
        setLoading(false);
    };
```

handleChanger

```js
    const handleChanger = (event, page) => {
        fetchPage(page);
        push({
            pathname: "/character",
            search: `?page=${page}`,
        });
```

Пагинация:

```js
                    <Pagination
                        count={info.pages}
                        showLastButton
                        showFirstButton
                        onChange={handleChanger}
                    />
```

Comment: Разместите значащий код в вопросе, в последствии ссылка на Ваш репозиторий может стать неактивной, и ответ на вопрос не будет нести смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: Изменил описание